# Write data to table correctly(ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two tables. They are linked.

Here is one

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Interviews] 
(
  [Interview_Id] INT  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
  [Greeting]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
  [Detail]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
  [VacancyId]    INT            NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Interview_Id] ASC),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_Interviews_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([VacancyId]) 
     REFERENCES [dbo].[Vacancies] ([VacancyId]) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

It's Interview table. For Interview I have QuestionBlocks

Here is QuestionBlock I have table like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QuestionBlocks] 
(
  [Block_ID]     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
  [Question1]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
  [Question2]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
  [Question3]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
  [Question4]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
  [Question5]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
  [Question6]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
  [Question7]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
  [Question8]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
  [Question9]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
  [Question10]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
  [Interview_Id] INT            NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Block_ID] ASC),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_QuestionBlocks_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([Interview_Id])    
       REFERENCES [dbo].[Interviews] ([Interview_Id])
);
```

Also I have two Views , in one I write Greeting and Details and select vacancy and Id of vacancy goes to `VacancyId` field

On next view I create questions and write them to Question1-Question10 fields.

But also I need to write Interview_Id to table. Interview_Id must be that created on previous View.

I want to know how to make logic like this right?

Maybe I need to write Interview_Id to variable anв pass it to another controller?

Or maybe I need to write it to Session?

Also I read about TempData, maybe it's better to use it?

**UPDATE** 
Here is QuestionBlock model

```
 public partial class QuestionBlock
{
    public int Block_ID { get; set; }
    public string Question1 { get; set; }
    public string Question2 { get; set; }
    public string Question3 { get; set; }
    public string Question4 { get; set; }
    public string Question5 { get; set; }
    public string Question6 { get; set; }
    public string Question7 { get; set; }
    public string Question8 { get; set; }
    public string Question9 { get; set; }
    public string Question10 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Interview_Id { get; set; }




    public virtual Interview Interview { get; set; }
}
```

And here is Interwiev Model

```
 public Interview()
    {
        this.Interwiers = new HashSet<Interwier>();
        this.InvitationMails = new HashSet<InvitationMail>();
        this.MassLinks = new HashSet<MassLink>();
        this.QuestionBlocks = new HashSet<QuestionBlock>();
    }

    public int Interview_Id { get; set; }
    public string Greeting { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> VacancyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Vacancy Vacancy { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Interwier> Interwiers { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<InvitationMail> InvitationMails { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<MassLink> MassLinks { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<QuestionBlock> QuestionBlocks { get; set; }
}
```

Controller for Question blocks

```
 // GET: Questions
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Question1 = new  SelectList(db.Questions,"question","question");
        ViewBag.Question2 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Question3 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Question4 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Question5 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Question6 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Question7 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Question8 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Question9 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
        ViewBag.Question10 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");

        return View(db.Questions.ToList());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string question1, string question2, string question3, string question4, string question5, string question6, string question7, string question8, string question9, string question10)
    {
        QuestionBlock question = new QuestionBlock
        {
            Question1 = question1,
            Question2 = question2,
            Question3 = question3,
            Question4 = question4,
            Question5 = question5,
            Question6 = question6,
            Question7 = question7,
            Question8 = question8,
            Question9 = question9,
            Question10 = question10,

        };
        db.QuestionBlocks.Add(question);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And here is controller for interview

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult WelcomeScreen()
    {
        // Формируем список команд для передачи в представление
       SelectList teams = new SelectList(db.Vacancy, "VacancyId", "VacancyName");
        ViewBag.Teams = teams;
        SelectList teams2 = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyID", "CompanyName");
        ViewBag.Teams2 = teams2;
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult WelcomeScreen( Interview interview)
    {
        db.Interview.Add(interview);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Questions");
    }
```

Comment: when do you need those variables to be write into database?

Comment: Can you please provide model views, views and controller code too?

Comment: I need it to write on View with question blocks where I have button after button click@Tacud

Comment: Yes, I will update question now@Mr.AF

Comment: I updateв my question@Tacud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you need to know the Interview_Id when you submit the questions and you are in this action method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string question1, string question2, string question3, string question4, string question5, string question6, string question7, string question8, string question9, string question10)
{ ... }
```

I don't know how your the view looks but you need to add a hidden field with the Interview_Id name and the correct value and also add one more parameter to the Index method

```
public ActionResult Index(int Inderview_Id, string question1, string question2, string question3, string question4, string question5, string question6, string question7, string question8, string question9, string question10)
{ ... }
```

I believe that this is the method, that is used to render the view with questions:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Question1 = new  SelectList(db.Questions,"question","question");
    ViewBag.Question2 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
    ViewBag.Question3 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
    ViewBag.Question4 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
    ViewBag.Question5 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
    ViewBag.Question6 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
    ViewBag.Question7 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
    ViewBag.Question8 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
    ViewBag.Question9 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");
    ViewBag.Question10 = new SelectList(db.Questions, "question", "question");

    return View(db.Questions.ToList());
}
```

I can see couple issues with that method:

- Why do you add all the questions to ViewBag and also return all the questions again as the model?
- Also, I guess, it's just a copy&paste error but it looks like you have a 10 identical list of questions?
- In order to be able to create the hidden field Interview_Id in the view, you need to get the value in this action method and pass it to the view, either by using the ViewBag or in the model.

I strongly recommend to create a view model and don't use ViewBag. Something like:

```
public class InterviewQuestionsView {
    public int Interview_Id { get; set; }
    public SelectList Question1 { get; set; }
    public SelectList Question2 { get; set; }
    public SelectList Question3 { get; set; }
    public SelectList Question4 { get; set; }
    public SelectList Question5 { get; set; }
    public SelectList Question6 { get; set; }
    public SelectList Question7 { get; set; }
    public SelectList Question8 { get; set; }
    public SelectList Question9 { get; set; }
    public SelectList Question10 { get; set; }
}
```

(but I'm pretty sure, it can be done even better - to avoid sending 10 instances of the same list, but I'm not sure it's really what you do) and use it in the cation method like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new InterviewQuestionsView {
        // fill with data
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view set the model to:

```
@model InterviewQuestionsView

//add the hidden field
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Interview_id)
```